# Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension when implementing JavaMail (in webapp)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, servlet-3.0

I'm new to Java and I was trying the JavaMail feature, and it keeps giving me this error when i run the program:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension

I ran it on a different project, and it worked fine until I integrated it in a web app. Now the error pops up.

Below is my servlet which gives error.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class SendMail extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet SendMail</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet SendMail at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
         
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

    String to=request.getParameter("to");  
    String subject=request.getParameter("subject");  
    String msg=request.getParameter("msg");  
          
    send();  
    System.out.println("message has been sent successfully");  
    
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
    
 public void send(){
     String to = "kezama1231@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
      String from = "kezama1231@gmail.com";  
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";//or IP address  
  
     //Get the session object  
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
    return new PasswordAuthentication(from,"123");  
      }  
    });  
  
     //compose the message  
      try{  
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
         message.setSubject("Ping");  
         message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  
  
         // Send message  
         Transport.send(message);  
         System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  
  
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

Below is the Java file I used

```java
import java.util.*;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  
import javax.activation.*;
  
public class Mailer {  

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String to = "kezama1231@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
          String from = "kezama1231@gmail.com";  
          String host = "localhost";//or IP address  
      
         //Get the session object  
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
        return new PasswordAuthentication(from,"123");  
          }  
        });  
      
         //compose the message  
          try{  
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
             message.setSubject("Ping");  
             message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  
      
             // Send message  
             Transport.send(message);  
             System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  
      
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLConfiguration.getEnabledExtensions(SSLConfiguration.java:380)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:562)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:110)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:233)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:602)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:376)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:193)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2151)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:716)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
    at SendMail.send(SendMail.java:127)
    at SendMail.doPost(SendMail.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I try to link the Java file with the servlet it gives the same error.

Comment: you can not to Snippets with java

Comment: Which version of JavaMail (or JakartaMail; the new name of JavaMail) are you using, and which version of Java?

Comment: depending on jdk version encryption  related classes  may be not available (due to US export controls and such)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am not sure since i downloaded it from javatpoint but I will try to update to the latest version and rerun in.

Comment: I tried using javamail 1.6 from https://javaee.github.io/javamail/ and openjdk15 but it still gives error

Answer (score 1):

I think this is OpenJDK class and you probably have standard JDK. Change your JDK to OpenJDK and this will work. You can download it from here https://adoptopenjdk.net/, here is your class on github https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLExtension.java so you can see it's inside OpenJDK. You can also download it directly from Intellij File -> Project Structure -> SDKs -> + icon -> download JDK.

Comment: Hi sir,yes i am using stardard jdk 8 and i downloaded the openJDK15 and HotSpot and added the platform in my netbeans through Tools -> Add Platform and rerun the project and it still gives me the same error :(  .

I am also gonna try to update my javamail jar file to the latest version in hopes of solving it .

Comment: Assuming by 'standard' you both mean Oracle, there is no difference in JSSE between Oracle and OpenJDK (and no difference in the rest of JCE except that in versions before late 2017 Oracle defaulted to the 'limited' crypto policy due to former US export rules, and you needed to add the 'unlimited policy' download, while OpenJDK ddi not). But there is in both a big difference between j11 up which implements TLS1.3, and 8u261 up which backports that code, versus all lower versions. Since the posted stacktrace is not modular, I deduce it was 8u261 up. ...

Comment: ... @C.Dog: AFAICS (both of) those can only fail initialization of that class if at least one of sysprops `jsse.enableSNIExtension jsse.enableMFLNExtension jsse.enableMFLExtension` has an invalid value (not `true` or `false`); try looking at those near the point of failure.